# SMD Electronics Part that could be used for hanging

Tags: surface-mount

I'm working on a decorative PCB and I want the ability to hang it up on a wall conveniently. I was trying to think of something that would work similar to the saw tooth looking piece in this example

[image: Frame Holder]

One requirement is that is has to be a surface mounted part. Something I thought of was a test point ( https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/harwin-inc/S1751-46R/952-1478-1-ND/2264564 ), but they don't seem to come in a large enough size to work. The other thing I thought of was using a battery holder ( https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/linx-technologies-inc/BAT-HLD-001-TR/BAT-HLD-001-TRCT-ND/5803803 ), which could work alright but is still a bit small.

I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas for common SMD electronics parts that could work with a household nail or screw.

Comment: My hunch is that anything surface mounted will be at risk of ripping the pad off the PCB. This doesn't take much force, at least with normal-size pads (on the scale of mm). Otherwise I would just suggest two big pads to hand-solder a wire between, to be hanged as larger frames. My second suggestion is to glue a normal attachment to the PCB.

Comment: I'd recommend browsing the pcb hardware vendors, like Keystone Electronics or RAF Hardware. You might find a fuse holder or a test point or something that will work for you.

Comment: @AndersPetersson I knew I was overthinking it, thank you for the two big pads with a wire between them idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such thing as PCB cut-out. You can make it exactly in a shape of sawtooth hanger near the top of pcb.

Another simple option is to use right-angle [rectangular header](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/GEC06SBSN-M89/S1113E-06-ND/862277) with pins facing down. If your PCB is heavy you can use either [shrouded](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/BM06B-ACHFKS-GACN-ETF-LF-SN/455-2881-2-ND/4234183) or [dual row](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/samtec-inc/TSM-105-02-T-DH/SAM12234-ND/6691923) headers.

Comment: It was the simple options I overlooked I was looking for. A standard pitch rectangular header should work great with a standard nail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using  SMT PEM Nuts this may work you will need to choose a low profile Nut.

[image]